# How can I check for a key press at any point during a loop?

Tags: python, keyboard

I am trying to make a timer that counts down to 0, then starts counting up. I am using the time and keyboard modules.
The [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard) module from PyPi.

Everything works as expected, and I am able to press a button to close the program, but it only works at the beginning of each iteration. Is there a way for it to check for a key press at any point while the loop is running? Do I need to be using a different module?

This is my code:

```
import time
import keyboard

m = 2
s = 0
count_down = True

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
        break
    print(f"{m} minutes, {s} seconds")
    if count_down:
        if s == 0:
            m -= 1
            s = 60
        s -= 1
    elif not count_down:
        s += 1
        if s == 60:
            m += 1
            s = 0
    if m == 0 and s == 0:
        count_down = False
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Python's standard library doesn't include a `keyboard` module. What third-party module are you trying to using?

Comment: The keyboard module is this one: https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/
Is there a better option that I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using callback is common approach in such case, here is solution:

```py
import time
import keyboard

m = 2
s = 0
count_down = True

break_loop_flag = False

def handle_q_button():
    print('q pressed')
    global break_loop_flag
    break_loop_flag = True

keyboard.add_hotkey('q', handle_q_button)

while True:
    if break_loop_flag:
        break
    print(f"{m} minutes, {s} seconds")
    if count_down:
        if s == 0:
            m -= 1q
            s = 60
        s -= 1
    elif not count_down:
        s += 1
        if s == 60:
            m += 1
            s = 0
    if m == 0 and s == 0:
        count_down = False
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: This still only checks at the start of the loop though - wasn't that the OP's problem?

Comment: @Grismar.. ohh.. I misunderstood your question, nevermind.. but still, your code didn't worked as suposed at my computer..

Comment: What do you mean by "your code" - you mean the code I offered in my own answer of the OP's question? How does it not work? Perhaps post a comment there?

Comment: @Grismar: The `break_loop_flag` can be checked at any time in the loop, so though the usage sample only does it once at the beginning, the callback technique it suggests _does_ answer the question IMO (and apparently the OP's).

Comment: The answer was accepted, no argument there - your answer and mine are complementary, hopefully both help in cases where they apply. No such thing as a single, best solution after all.

Comment: @Grismar I am working in VSCode in Jupyter environment. Your original code was not handling 'q' event, in 100%. I have to do some change of focus and press `q` in different positions and then sometimes code handle it. Maybe thats why I misunderstood your question, cos at beginning I was trying to fix this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do any two things in parallel, independently of another, you need to consider using `multiprocessing`. However, even if you do, your loop will either still need to check if a key has been registered in the other process, or you need to terminate the process running the loop forcefully, which may result in unexpected outcomes.

However, in your case, since there are no side effects like files being written, this would work:

```
import time
import keyboard
from multiprocessing import Process


def print_loop():
    m = 2
    s = 0
    count_down = True

    while True:
        print(f"{m} minutes, {s} seconds")
        if count_down:
            if s == 0:
                m -= 1
                s = 60
            s -= 1
        elif not count_down:
            s += 1
            if s == 60:
                m += 1
                s = 0
        if m == 0 and s == 0:
            count_down = False
        time.sleep(1)


def main():
    p = Process(target=print_loop)
    p.start()
    # this loop runs truly in parallel with the print loop, constantly checking
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
            break
    # force the print loop to stop immediately, without finishing the current iteration
    p.kill()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```