# How to get key from keyboard while doing another task?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I'm trying to build a Snake game using python, but I'm struggling with the input system. In the snake game, the snake walks through the same direction until someone change his direction.

The way I did was stopping the snake from moving while waits for the next key, but that's not what I want. The snake must walk to the same direction until receive an input to change direction.

How to do the get the key so the snake changes his direction while moving it through the screen and colliding with objects?

```
import os
from msvcrt import getch

class SnakeGame(object):
    screen = None

    def __init__(self, rows_count, column_count):
        self.screen = self.initialize_screen(rows_count, column_count)
        self.collided = False

    def initialize_screen(self, rows_count, column_count):
        #creates the 2D list with 0 in all values
        screen = [[0 for x in range(column_count)] for y in range(rows_count)]

        #get the rows
        for row in range(len(screen)):
            if row == 0 or row == len(screen) - 1:
                screen[row] = self.add_same_value_entire_list(screen[row], 1)
            else:
                for column in range(len(screen[row])):
                    if column == 0 or column == len(screen[row]) - 1:
                        screen[row][column] = 1

        return screen

    def add_same_value_entire_list(self, list, value):
        populatedList = [value for i in range(len(list))]

        return populatedList

    def print_screen(self):
        screen_text = ''
        for row in self.screen:
            for column in row:
                screen_text = screen_text + self.translated_value(column)

            screen_text = screen_text + '\n'
        return screen_text

    def translated_value(self, value):
        if value == 1:
            return '#'
        elif value == 2:
            return '*'
        elif value == -1: #snake body
            return 'O'
        elif value == -2: #moving left snake head left <----
            return '<'
        elif value == -3: #moving right  snake head right ---->
            return '>'
        elif value == -4: #moving down
            return 'V'
        elif value == -5: #moving up
            return '^'
        else:
            return ' '

    def play(self):
        player = Player()
        key_pressed = 9999
        self.add_player_to_screen(player)

        while(self.defeated() is not True and key_pressed != 27):
            self.clear()
            print(self.print_screen())
            key_pressed = self.read_key()
            player.move(self.translate_key(key_pressed))
            self.add_player_to_screen(player)

    def read_key(self):
        return ord(getch())

    def add_player_to_screen(self, player):
        print(player.location_x)
        print(player.location_y)
        if(player.position_cordination == 'E'):
            self.screen[player.location_x][player.location_y - 1] = 0
        elif (player.position_cordination == 'W'):
            self.screen[player.location_x][player.location_y + 1] = 0
        elif (player.position_cordination == 'N'):
            self.screen[player.location_x + 1][player.location_y] = 0
        elif (player.position_cordination == 'S'):
            self.screen[player.location_x - 1][player.location_y] = 0

        if(self.screen[player.location_x][player.location_y] == 0):
            self.screen[player.location_x][player.location_y] = player.body
        elif(self.screen[player.location_x][player.location_y] < 0):
            self.collided = True

    def translate_key(self, key):
        print (key)
        if (key == 224):
            key = ord(getch())
            print(key)
            if (key == 72):
                return 'N'
            elif (key == 80):
                return 'S'
            elif (key == 75):
                return 'W'
            elif (key == 77):
                return 'E'
        else:
            pass

    def defeated(self):
        return self.collided

    def clear(self):
        os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.nodes_size = 1
        self.position_cordination = 'E'
        self.last_cordination = 'E'
        self.location_x = 4
        self.location_y = 4
        self.body = -3

    def draw(self):
        body = ''
        for index in range(self.nodes_size):
            if(index == 0 and self.position_cordination == 'E'):
                body = '>'
            elif(index == 0 and self.position_cordination == 'W'):
                body = '<'
            elif(index == 0 and self.position_cordination == 'N'):
                body = '^'
            elif(index == 0 and self.position_cordination == 'S'):
                body = 'V'
            else:
                body += '-'

        return body

    def move(self, cordination):
        print("Cordinations x = " + str(self.location_x) + " y = " + str(self.location_y))
        if (self.position_cordination != 'S' and cordination == 'N'):
            self.location_x -= 1
            self.body = -5
        elif (self.position_cordination != 'N' and cordination == 'S'):
            self.location_x +=1
            self.body = -4
        elif (self.position_cordination != 'W' and cordination == 'E'):
            self.location_y += 1
            self.body = -3
        elif (self.position_cordination != 'E' and cordination == 'W'):
            self.location_y -= 1
            self.body = -2
        else:
            pass

        self.position_cordination = cordination
        print("Cordinations x = " + str(self.location_x) + " y = " + str(self.location_y))

snake = SnakeGame(32, 32)
snake.play()
```

Comment: `Snake` implementation is covered in *many* examples on Stack Overflow and elsewhere on line.

Comment: I've found some examples using windows-curses package, but didn't found one that helped me with the issue that I'm struggling. Can someone help me with some way to get the input while performing another task?

Comment: You need to set up keystroke event handlers.

Comment: The `msvcrt` module also has a `kbhit()` function you can use to check if a key has been pressed without blocking.

Comment: Also see [How can I check for a key press at any point during a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60031916/how-can-i-check-for-a-key-press-at-any-point-during-a-loop)

Comment: If you want cross-platform, you should design the entire game as a curses application. Python's standard library doesn't support curses in Windows, but there are a couple of third-party ports available.