# Is there any way to limit the amount of keystrokes captured?

Tags: python, keyboard, python-2.x

I'm trying to learn the [keyboard module](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) in python, and increment certain values by 1. However whenever I press a key it seems the switch will hold on longer than expected, and instead of incrementing by 1 it will increment by 6 or more.

```
import keyboard

x = 10
y = 10

while True:

    counter = 0
    if x < 0:
        x = 0
    if y < 0:
        y = 0

    if keyboard.is_pressed('up'):
       y += 1
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('down'):
       y -= 1
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('right'):
       x += 1
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('left'):
       x -= 1

    print 'x =' ,x, 'y =', y
```

Even a slight tap from one of the keys causes this, is there anyway to remedy it?

Comment: how are you executing this code?

Comment: You mihgt be able to do it by creating callbacks for the keys you are interested in and have them increment / decrement the variables. For an example see accepted answer to  [How can I check for a key press at any point during a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60031916/how-can-i-check-for-a-key-press-at-any-point-during-a-loop) (and not need to use your infinite `while` loop).

Comment: THank you martin! It worked like a charm!